# Jquery href anchor value

Tags: jquery, anchor

I am having an anchor link in aspx page like:

```
<a id="Anchor"class="myAnchor" href="Myproject/Mypage.aspx?myTag=asp">Go</a>
```

I need to access the "myTag" value using jquery.How to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by value? The id? The href? The inlying text?

Comment: Sorry my question was actually not clear.I want only last part of the href, I mean "myTag" value only that is in this case 'asp'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var myTag = $('#Anchor')[0].search.split('=')[1];
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/B6GYB/

Or not using jQuery:

```
var myTag = document.getElementById('Anchor').search.split('=')[1];
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/B6GYB/1/

Comment: really a great one.Thanks a lot.

Comment: but one thing suppose 'myTag=asp net', then it gives result 'asp+net'. One + symbol appears, is there any way so that out put will be 'asp net' only?

Comment: @ANP - Sure, just add `.replace('+', ' ')` to the end.

Answer (score 11):

```
$(function(ready){
    alert($('#Anchor').attr('href')); // prints Myproject/Mypage.aspx?tag=asp
    alert($('#Anchor').text()); // prints Go
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/max6s/

Answer (score 2):

To get the href of the link:

```
var href = $('#Anchor').attr('href');
```

To get the HTML inside:

```
var html = $('#Anchor').html();
```

`#Anchor` is the CSS-format selector that means, "Select the element with the ID 'Anchor'."

Answer (score 0):

You can get the specific query parameter of url by using following code:

**Javascript**

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>         function getAnchorValue(anchorId, key) {
>             var href = document.getElementById(anchorId).getAttribute('href');
>             var pageQuerySearch = new PageQuery(href.split('?')[1]);
>             return unescape(unescape(pageQuerySearch.getValue(key)));
>         }
>         function PageQuery(query) {
>             if (query.length > 1) {this.q = query; } else { this.q = null; } this.keyValuePairs = new Array();
>             if (this.q) { for (var i = 0; i < this.q.split("&").length; i++) { this.keyValuePairs[i] = this.q.split("&")[i]; } };
>             this.getValue = function (s) {
>                 for (var j = 0; j < this.keyValuePairs.length; j++) {
>                     if (this.keyValuePairs[j].split("=")[0] == s) { return this.keyValuePairs[j].split("=")[1]; }
>                 } return false;
>             };
>         }
> </script>
> ```

and here is the usage of this function:

> alert(getAnchorValue('Anchor', 'myTag'));

**JQuery**

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     ; (function ($) {
>         $.extend({
>             getAnchorValue: function (name, url) {
>                 function getQueryStringParams() {
>                     var parameters = {}, e, a = /\+/g, r = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
>                         d = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(a, " ")); },
>                         q = url ? url.split('?')[1] : window.location.search.substring(1);
>                     while (e = r.exec(q)) { parameters[d(e[1])] = d(e[2]) }; return parameters;
>                 }
>                 if (!this.params) this.params = getQueryStringParams();
>                 return this.params[name];
>             }
>         });
>     })(jQuery);
> </script>
> ```

Usage:

> alert($.getAnchorValue('myTag', $('#Anchor').attr('href')));

**EDIT**: I have editted my answer and also added the jquery code for getting the querystring parameter

Comment: jQuery was not the requirement. the requirement was to get the value of tag.

Comment: "I need to access the "myTag" value using jquery.How to do this?" - It was required.

Comment: @Marwelln, @KARASZI István, I have editted my answer and added the jquery function to get the parameter value from an anchor's href.