# How to take out the div's id displaying in the url ? - JS Fiddle Added

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the given fiddle, I tried to develop a modal window using only html5 and css3 . The modal window is working fine but the div's id is being displayed with the url, so if i just click back without closing the modal window and come back, the modal window remains opened.

I know its all because of the div's id is getting added with the URL when the modal window is opened and its id is displayed with the url like this

```
http://localhost:90/modal.html#divModalDialog1
```

How can i remove the modal div's id from the url ?

JS Fiddle -  http://jsfiddle.net/bala2111/4UCGL/4/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Modal CSS 3</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        /*** pop-up div to cover entire area ***/
         .divModalDialog  {
            position:fixed;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            /*! important !*/
            display:none;
            /* last attribute set darkness on scale: 0...1.0 */
            background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
            text-align:center;
            z-index:101;
        } 

        /*** ! target attribute does the job ! ***/
         .divModalDialog:target  { display:block; } 

        /*** virtual frame containing controls, image and caption ***/
         .divModalDialog div  {
           /* either absolute or fixed */
            position:fixed;
            top:5%;
            width:100%;
            height:80%;
            /* rounded corners */
            -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            z-index:102;
        }

        #manual{
        width:920px;height:440px;
        background-color:#ffffff;
        position:absolute;
        margin-left:200px;
        }

        #close{
        margin-left:890px;
        }

</style>
<script>
function test()
{
    //alert('aaa');
    //window.history.go(-1);
    window.location.href="http://localhost/html_modal/test.php";
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- NAV THUMBNAILS -->
    <div id="divThumbnails">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#divModalDialog1">Click Me</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!--1st LINK -->
    <div id="divModalDialog1" class="divModalDialog">
        <div id="manual"><span id="close"><a href="#" onclick="test();"><img src="images/close_icon.png" /></a></span></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check this and see if helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001786/get-part-of-url-using-jquery , did you search in stack anything about this ? there is a plain of stuffs about ur'ls

Comment: i think you may have forgotten to save your fiddle - there is nothing after the body tag in the html and also there is no script code in it

Comment: @Mike C Yes, i think i need to know more about fiddle :)...Hopefully the link should work now..please check it

Comment: @RicardoArruda I did checked that same link, but that is not exactly am looking for, but similar to that. So i thought i could add a fiddle and ask a question

Comment: You should move all of your fiddle code into the question. The question is not helpful if none of your code is here and JSFiddle goes down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your div default non-visible en make it visible with javascript.