# Extract URL from document.write()

Tags: regex, url, find, extract, document.write

I have a simple html page that sources a javascript file. The javascript file's only purpose is to write the following...

```
document.write('<a href="http://www.linktosite.com"><img src="http://www.location.com/image.png"></a>');
```

Once the information has been written, im needing some javascript to extract the url and the image source and return the url and image locations alone.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you able to modify that JS file? If yes, add an `id` attribute to the anchor, and then use `document.getElementById()` to retrieve it.

Comment: Unfortunantly, i am not able to modify the JS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059193/jquery-href-anchor-value) which gives shows you how to do it with JQuery or just plain Javascript

**UPDATE:**

If you have the ability to modify the HTML, then why don't you put in a DOM element that you can hook on to right after where the image will be inserted?  Then you can use the following JQuery:

```
var linkDest = $('#Anchor').prev().attr('href');
var imgSrc = $('#Anchor').prev().children().attr('src');
```

Which you can see in [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/htUcC/)

Comment: I feel your answer is on the right track, but their method requires me to have an id in the <a> tag. I do not have access to modify that info.

Comment: Do you have the ability to add anything to the html?

Comment: Yes, i can add anything to the HTML.

Comment: See the updated answer (and accompanying JSFiddle Example) and let me know if that's a possibility.  If not, please explain what the issues are so that we can construct a solution that will work.

Comment: This works great in JSfiddle! When i plug the code into my site, i get different results. Here is my current code. I am also including jquery 1.7.2.    <div id="org_ad">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='myURL'></script>
    <span id="Anchor" />
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    alert($('#Anchor').prev().attr('href'));
    alert($('#Anchor').prev().children().attr('src'));
    </script>

Comment: Oh geez, sorry about the above comment. Code is below.

Comment: <script type='text/javascript' src='myURL'></script>

<span id="Anchor" />
<script type='text/javascript'>
alert($('#Anchor').prev().attr('href'));
alert($('#Anchor').prev().children().attr('src'));

</script>

Comment: The result of the code above is "undefined" and the next alert is "myURL". So it seems that the "document.write" isn't even writing before jquery gets ahold of it. BTW, thank you for your help!

Comment: Is your website live?  If not then I'll try to replicate the situation locally.  Also, is that JS file writing "myURL"?  Where did that come from?

Not a problem.  I'm just learning JQuery so I find this to be a fun challenge

Comment: The issue was that i was wrapping the "document.write" in a div that was throwing the javascript off. I got rid of the DIV and we are in business!

Comment: Not a problem.  Be sure to mark the answer correct if it helped you!  Glad to see you got it working